# Escape @ using awk

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, awk, cut

I have the following:

`ssh $DOMAIN -l root "grep "'$EMAIL@$DOMAIN'" /var/log/maillog | grep retr= | grep -v retr=0 | awk '{ print "'$11'" }' | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d= -f2 | awk '{ t += $1 } END { print "'total: '", t, "' bytes transferred over POP3'"}'"`

Running this command gives the following output:

> stdin: is not a tty
>
> awk: { t += blah@email.com } END { print total: , t,  bytes transferred over POP3}
>
> awk:              ^ invalid char '@' in expression

Looks like the issue is with `awk '{ t += $1 }` because of the @ in $1, however I've tried several different methods of escaping this with no luck. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried \@ or /@ ?

Comment: Since it's part of `awk '{ t += $1 }` I've tried escaping it via `awk '{ t += \$1 }` with no luck.

Comment: What's the actual goal this script is intended to accomplish? If you provide sample input and output, we might be able to provide a better solution (as opposed to this huge, ugly pipeline).

Comment: Most of the things you're doing here (grep, cut, etc) can be done natively in bash... or in a single awk script (awk is actually a full programming language).

Comment: Bang it all in shell script and do `ssh $DOMAIN -l root script.sh`

Comment: Unless your huge command line is executed from a shell script having 11 arguments or more, the $11 inside ``awk '{ print "'$11'" }'`` is useless because it is equivalent to ``awk '{print "" }``

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the command you ran, because the quotes don't match up (there's a superfluous `"`). It sounds like the command you actually ran expanded "$1", thus causing awk to interpret a literal email address instead of reading from the first field.

The final part should be:

```
awk '{ t += $1 } END { print "total: ", t, " bytes transferred over POP3"}'
```